# Is there a way in pandas to see how many rows belong to each year-month if we only have a start and end date?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

`ID | Start Date | End Date`  
`1  |2017-01-01  | 2017-08-01`
`2  |2017-01-01  | 2017-08-01`
`3  |2017-12-01  | 2018-05-01`
`4  |2018-03-02  | 2018-10-02`

I would like to see how many unique IDs fall in each month.  The start and end dates are datetime objects that provide a timeframe for which the ID can be counted.  In other words, the ID should be counted for every year-month combo that falls within the `Start Date` and `End Date`.

Ideally, the output would be something like this:

`YearMonth | Count`  
`Jan-2017  | 2`      
`Feb-2017  | 2`      
`Mar-2017  | 2`      
`...`                
`Dec-2017  | 1`      
`...`                
`Mar-2018  | 2`

I've tried creating a new DataFrame with all YearMonth combinations, but the logic I come up with by masking always seems to miss records and miscount.

Comment: Yes, these are date objects.  Here is the dtypes output:  
`ID             int64`  
`StartDate           datetime64[ns]`    
`EndDate             datetime64[ns]`    
I'm importing data from a CSV so I don't have code that actually creates the df other than a read_csv() statement

Comment: Is the `End Date` necessary to produce expected output?

Comment: @ipj yes, the `End Date` allows me to see at what month I should stop counting that ID

Comment: Can you check if my answer is giving the correct output?

Comment: @Terry your answer gives the correct output, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you need to create a temporary DF with a cross_join using min and max dates that can be found in DF. 
After this you need to [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) your data using [`.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html). [`.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) will count the unique IDs in each year-month

```
df['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Date'])
df['End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Date'])

d = pd.DataFrame({'dates': pd.date_range(df['Start_Date'].min(), 
                                         df['End_Date'].max(), freq='M')})

df_temp = (df.assign(dummy = 1)
             .merge(d.assign(dummy = 1), on= 'dummy')
             .query('dates >= Start_Date & dates <= End_Date')
          )

new_df = df_temp.groupby(df_temp['dates'].dt.strftime('%b-%Y'))['ID'].nunique().reset_index()
#to sort the DF
new_df = new_df.assign(dates = pd.to_datetime(new_df['dates'], format='%b-%Y')).sort_values('dates')
new_df['dates'] = new_df['dates'].dt.strftime('%b-%Y')

#output:
    dates       ID
6   Jan-2017    2
4   Feb-2017    2
12  Mar-2017    2
0   Apr-2017    2
14  May-2017    2
10  Jun-2017    2
8   Jul-2017    2
3   Dec-2017    1
7   Jan-2018    1
5   Feb-2018    1
13  Mar-2018    2
1   Apr-2018    2
15  May-2018    1
11  Jun-2018    1
9   Jul-2018    1
2   Aug-2018    1
16  Sep-2018    1
```

Comment: Looks like `Mar-2018` should be `2` ?

Comment: and `Aug-2018`, `May-2018` should be 2 as well... the problem is with daterange not including the last month if the date is the first date of the month (eg. `2017-08-01`)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely not the cleanest, and someone might come up with a "pure" pandas solution, but for now this can get you in the right direction.

```
from datetime import timedelta

def build_date_ranges(r):
    return tuple((r['Start Date'] + timedelta(n)).strftime('%b-%Y')
                 for n in range((r['End Date'] - r['Start Date']).days))

df['parsed_dates'] = df.apply(build_date_ranges, axis=1)
print(df.explode('parsed_dates').groupby('parsed_dates')['ID'].nunique())
```

Outputs

```
parsed_dates
Apr-2017    2
Apr-2018    2
Aug-2018    1
Dec-2017    1
Feb-2017    2
Feb-2018    1
Jan-2017    2
Jan-2018    1
Jul-2017    2
Jul-2018    1
Jun-2017    2
Jun-2018    1
Mar-2017    2
Mar-2018    2
May-2017    2
May-2018    1
Oct-2018    1
Sep-2018    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a series with all the months between Start/End dates by casting to period and using `pd.period_range` as in

```
all_months = pd.Series([
    pd.period_range(start, end).to_series().values
    for start, end in zip(df['Start Date'].dt.to_period('M').values,
        df['End Date'].dt.to_period('M').values)
]).explode(ignore_index=True)
```

Now get the occurrence of each month with

```
count = all_months.groupby(all_months).size()
```

Output

```
2017-01    2
2017-02    2
2017-03    2
2017-04    2
2017-05    2
2017-06    2
2017-07    2
2017-08    2
2017-12    1
2018-01    1
2018-02    1
2018-03    2
2018-04    2
2018-05    2
2018-06    1
2018-07    1
2018-08    1
2018-09    1
2018-10    1
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```